# how window.location having again redirect in php file?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am using the JS `window.location` as:

```
window.location.href = "my_url.php?param=1"
```

`my_url.php` having again redirect using `header()` function.

If `param=1` I am having code for **download CSV**, otherwise redirect to other URL.

**UPDATE:**

Redirect using JS:

```
    // Download CSV 
$( '#download_csv' ).on( 'click', function() {
        window.location.href ="my_url.php?param=1"; //  param is dynamic will be sent or not
    });
```

**my_url.php**

```
    if($param == 1)
    {
        //CODE for download CSV, It works fine as intended
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:other_page.php");//no actual redirect happens, instead I got ajax output of other_page.php    
        exit;
    }
```

**Problem:** whatever the output of other_page.php it will get printed but my Addressbar is having the URL of my_url.php

Comment: What is the problem? If you redirect, you  redirect

Comment: please show what you've done

Comment: _Kindly provide some solution_ to what? It will redirect, if you have coded so.

Comment: You question is not clear we can help but we need to know what do you need help with.

Comment: So what is the problem again?  What is expected and actual result?

Comment: no actual redirect happens, instead I got ajax output of other_page.php

Comment: there is no ajax call in your code then how can you get ajax output?

Comment: that's the problem, whatever the output of other_page.php it will get printed but my Addressbar is having the URL of my_url.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `param` in **my_url.php** and according to it if you have to redirect then check param using $_GET then apply redirection

**my_url.php**

```
$param = (isset($GET['param']))?GET['param']:"";
if($param == 1)
{
    //CODE for download CSV, 
}
else
{
    header("Location:other_page.php");//redirect to other page
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That is not working, hence the question posted. It gives me ajax output of other_page.php not redirect

Comment: `window.location.href` redirect you to other page. If you are using ajax then update your question with full code. In your question you don't have specify anything about ajax. Your question is not clear